# Typescript having problem with getting correct type while filtering some types from union type

Tags: typescript, union-types

I have code similar to this:

```
type Foo = {
  products:
    | {
        fooName: string;
      }
    | {
        fooName: string;
      }[]
    | null;
  amount: number;
}[];

const exampleObj = { products: { fooName: 'Foo' }, amount: 13 };

const foo: Foo = [
  exampleObj,
  exampleObj,
  { products: [{ fooName: 'Foo' }, { fooName: 'Foo' }], amount: 14 },
] as Foo;

const bar = foo.map((el) => {
  if (!el.products || Array.isArray(el.products)) {
    return exampleObj;
  }

  return el;
});

bar.forEach((el)=> {
  console.log(el.products.fooName)
})
```

this code works as expected - element in foo that has product value set to array is filtered out while mapping through foo. Bar has third element set to exampleObj.

My problem is that typescript suggests type of bar is:

```
const bar: {
    products: {
        fooName: string;
    } | {
        fooName: string;
    }[] | null;
    amount: number;
}[]
```

and I get an error:

```
Property 'fooName' does not exist on type '{ fooName: string; } | { fooName: string; }[]'.
  Property 'fooName' does not exist on type '{ fooName: string; }[]'.
```

I can fix this error by casting bar with

```
const bar = foo.map((el) => {
  if (!el.products || Array.isArray(el.products)) {
    return exampleObj;
  }

  return el;
}) as typeof exampleObj[]
```

but am I missing something or typescript just can't understand what is going on in that code?

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Neidz/pen/qBJyjWa (but as far as I know you will not get type suggestions or typescript errors here)

Comment: This is a missing feature of TS, suggested at [ms/TS#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384).  Since `Foo` is not a discriminated union type, checking a property doesn't narrow `Foo` itself, it only narrows the property you checked.  Right now the easiest workaround would be to copy the narrowed property into a new object (which is weird but at least works) as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mqx3QN). Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: It does, thank you. The solution is truly unexpected but you are right, it works

Comment: Okay I'll write an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've run into a missing feature of TypeScript, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384). TypeScript doesn't currently propagate the results of [narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) an object property up to the parent object.  (Well, except if that parent object is of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type, but `Foo[number]` is just a single object type, not a union at all, and therefore definitely not a discriminated union.)  So checking `el.products` property only serves to narrow `el.products` and not `el`.

If you want to see this feature implemented, it wouldn't hurt for you to go to it and give a .  It probably wouldn't *help* much either, though.

---

Anyway, until and unless we get support for the feature, you'll need to work around it.  One way to do so is to copy the narrowed property over into a new object, since that will force the compiler to go through the analysis of the applying the narrowed type to the property in the new object:

```
const bar = foo.map((el) => {
   if (!el.products || Array.isArray(el.products)) {
      return exampleObj;
   }
   const ret = { ...el, products: el.products };
   /* const ret: {
    products: {
        fooName: string;
    };
    amount: number;  } */
   return ret;
});

bar.forEach((el) => {
   console.log(el.products.fooName); // okay
})
```

Or, a little more ergonomically:

```
const bar = foo.map((el) => {
   const { products, ...restEl } = el;
   if (!products || Array.isArray(products)) {
      return exampleObj;
   }
   return { ...restEl, products }
});

bar.forEach((el) => {
   console.log(el.products.fooName); // okay
});
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAUFLYBOcAmArgMbADOAXFABSZb2pQBmCAcgIYC2EVZwOASwB2AcwDcUAL5QAPnXppmbLjyh9BoiZIDaAXVnz6QwgBsT8gJRj5XOISHAqxzgCMIOazt3X0xOEL4oCAAPLjATCAB5FwArZEVcAhJyKkYWOA5uKgByeDhsqQAaKFt7RygARgBmKR8-AOAlOCo8+O15ELCI6JjCjtDOcKjYvoYoRKJSSihtNOUsqFyEAsliuYyVHLyV3WLShyoKgBYi9H12MlgEayEVMjB2YmgYAWCKtHl6wJd2HHj0gB0nHYYGo1AgJgsyAAfB8FFgBEwaABCCEAibJS4yGRQACCOBw7BAAIEZHxhJA4JM6Lwk3IFihGHhChwEGAhBwQiCAyGPWszMkhiwX0arMaKEYAKlEOKGKmVDRcvItSFUAA9AAqKAiqBi1Kq8a0zH65nw9KZVTqYTiA2SfnM-blZxuDxYaQatWqsUcrli+1SKzoeQ-HAAlg4ACijwAFmCIVCkLCmfCvnAIgCTHARFSaUkpmH5hArOq1VA4ABrInySQWIPoQXoW7ce6PZ6vABMH0+-m+v3+CCBILjkJhcJTPcajCVZGKUoBrL4EZMUniEP99ERKOnshx5KJJLJBKJ1GnDLHpu9nO5XWGMXXbq9bJ9ijnC+AS9lRqmUmrgeDvwLSMY2HBMk1VVN00zbNFS-cgCw2bhizVUsKyregayDSQgA)